# Write Data / Changes In Excel Sheet Via Robot Framework Not Working and Getting IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, excel, robotframework

I'm trying to read a Transaction ID from website and put that information in Excel Sheet via Robot Framework by creating the sheet using timestamp in the same file. I have saved the required Transaction ID in a variable, but when i'm trying to put this value to an excel file it is not saving any the changes that I'm doing to the file.

I tried two different things -

1.) First - I tried to create a new sheet in the file to check whether it is getting saved or not. Of course this new sheet did not get created but there are no errors, test case was passed. I have created a keyword which I'm calling with two arguments File_Name and Sheet_Name, they are coming correctly as I checked them after printing on log console

```
Create New Sheet
[Arguments]    ${File_Name}    ${Sheet_Name}

 Log To Console    ${File_Name}    
 Log To Console    ${Sheet_Name}    

#Now Open Excel and add the sheet and save it
    Open Excel        ${File_Name}
    Add New Sheet     ${Sheet_Name}
    sleep    1s
    Save Excel        Transaction_File.xls
```

2.) Second - Once I got to knew that new sheet is not getting created in the file, so I thought to try writing the data to existing sheet which gets created by default on creating a new .xls file i.e. Sheet1, Here i'm getting below error - `IndexError: list index out of range`

Below is the keyword which I have created -

```
Create Header For New Sheet
[Arguments]    ${File_Name}    ${Sheet_Name}        

#Create a new header
    Open Excel  ${File_Name}

    Log To Console    ${File_Name}
    Log To Console    ${Sheet_Name} 

    Put String To Cell    ${Sheet_Name}    1    2    Sr.No
    Put String To Cell    ${Sheet_Name}    2    2    Scenario_Name
    Put String To Cell    ${Sheet_Name}    3    2    Test Case Name
    Put String To Cell    ${Sheet_Name}    4    2    Status
    Put String To Cell    ${Sheet_Name}    5    2    Comments/Values

#Now save the changes
    Save Excel    Transaction_File.xls
```

Below is the code which I have written in my test suite

```
 *** Variables ***
 ${File_Name}    C:\\Automation\\Automation_Details.xls
 ${Sheet_Name}   Transaction_File.xls

 *** Test Cases ***
  Create New Sheet    ${File_Name}    ${Sheet_Name}
   Create Header For New Sheet    ${File_Name}    Sheet1
```

Also below is the output for Log To Console -

```
  C:\Automation\Automation_Details.xls
  Transactions_201908190359
```

Could you please suggest or point what I'm doing wrong in order to fix this issue related to Data Writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this answer so that if any person is facing some issues in similar manner could be using it.

Step -1 Write a simple python code to read and write in excel. In python this could be done easily via xlrd / xlwt.

Step -2 Import that python file in your code.

Step -3 Call the method directly, you won't be facing any issues

***Please Note*** :-

> Keep the .xls files inside your project, may be try to create a folder
>   inside your project and then call it from there, this would remove a
>   lot of unwanted issues.